# How can I draw alphabet letters on screen using jQuery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Let's say I have a html table with cells background as red. I would like to print alphabet letters(A-Z) in a loop on the table using jquery, for example letter J would look like as in the following image:

[Click here to view the image](http://i42.tinypic.com/vht6vb.jpg)

I can create a table and a pointer which can loop through all the cells of the table and change the background color to black. However, I don't understand which cells to highlight for a particular alphabet. For example, to display letter "A" on a 30 x 30 table, which cells do I need to change its background such that I get letter A displayed on the screen and so on for other letters. Is there any pattern for this?

Here is the code i have so far:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var x=0;
        var y=1;
        function movePointer(){
            printCell();
            if(x==30){
                x=0;
                y++;
            }
            if(y==31){
                y=1;
                x=0;
                $(".pointer").css("background","red");
            }
            x++;
        }

        function printCell(){
            $("#"+x+"_"+y).css("background","black");
        }
        function eraseCell(){
        }
        setInterval(movePointer,1);
    });
</script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0; padding:0">
        <?php
            $h=30;
            $v=30;
            echo "<table border='1'>";
            for($y=1;$y<=$v;$y++){
                echo "<tr>";
                for($x=1;$x<=$h;$x++){
                    echo "<td style='border:1px solid red; width:20px; height:20px'>";
                    echo "<div style='width:20px; height: 20px; background:red' class='pointer' id='".$x."_".$y."'></div>";
                    echo "</td>";
                }
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Just curios: What do you want to use this for?

Comment: cam from what i can understand from your comments you are actually having 2 issues, one how to extract the bitmap from a letter, and two how to draw it on the screen. for the second i've provided you with a solution for the first you should either post a new question or edit the actual one.

Comment: yeah but to extract it, i need to create it first. So it goes hand in hand. Without the first how can i get the second

Answer (score 2):

To achieve such a thing you will require something like a "**bitmap**", so you will need an **alphabet map/array** that has attached for **each** element another **array** that has the **index** of squares to be colored differently.

EDIT:

A simple example would be using something like:

```
var alphabet = ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz").split("");
var letterBitmap = {};
$.each(alphabet,function(index,data){
letterBitmap[data] = new Array("1.1");
console.log(letterBitmap[data]);
});
```

Take note that the line that says new Array("1.2") is actually the coordinate for the first block that needs to be collored, given 1 as the row and 2 as the column. For a letter you should have something like:

new Array("1.1","2.3","5.2") etc., note that the coordinates are not valid they are just as proof of concept.

After you have data in such a format it is very simple to go trough that Array of coordinates, split them and choose the right index to color.

Hope it helps.

Comment: well it's not supposed to display anything that is your job to do :) i have just provided you with a starting point on how to build your bitmap

Comment: but my question is how to do i get the coordinates for each letter?

Comment: You could play with a canvas, or do it server side with php.

Comment: how can i achieve it with server side php?

Comment: ... create a image > draw a glyph > read every pixel to find out the ones filled and the ones left blank > put that data in an array > output it to javascript > repeat for other glyphs > profit!

Comment: how to draw alphabets on screen using php?

Comment: Not a php expert, go to google and try searching for PHP IMAGE or something.

Answer (score 0):

You could create some sort of Bitmap for each Letter as a Multidimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple html that let you draw the letters by clicking on the cells. Then return a hex number with the state of the cells. Then use the resulting data in your code.

Other option would be to search in google for some "Ascii font table" (I tried, ..not luck) with the letters already done.

If everything fails, you can use the console command "banner" to generate this text for a-Z.

The easier way is to write this mini-draw html tool :D